# Identify whether there is decimal points or not

Tags: java

I have a problem where my application crashes if the user enters no decimal point after `(DOT)`. For example `23.25` is valid, but when the user leaves `23.` without entering any values after decimal it crashes.

How can i figure out this and throw a message to user saying, you have not entered any `decimal point` after `DOT`.

Comment: Where does the app crash? Are you parsing with Double.parseDouble(input) or something similar or where is the problem?

Comment: is 23 valid? it has no DOT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String test=23.

use test.endsWith(".");

Answer (score 0):

check the `indexOf()` `.` in the entered `String` it shouldn't be `-1` OR `string.length()`

Comment: Unecessary O(n) process to check only last index.

Comment: Shouldn't that read `-1` (not present) or `String.length()-1` (last character)?

Comment: @ShashwatKumar you need to check the whole string to verify a dot is present at all. I agree you can do `test.contains('.') && test.charAt(test.length() - 1) != '.'` to simplify things. But you're not going to beat O(n).

Comment: In OP only '.' at last place is causing crash. He didn't say anything about other place. So only last index requires a check.

Comment: Yeah, that's correct, although i slightly strange requirement to me.

Answer (score 0):

You may `split()` on `.`, and the resulting array's second field should not be empty. Also, it's easily extensible to check for several decimal points (i.e. there surely should not be more than 2 fields in that array).

Comment: @Reddy what's with the wink? Are you coming on to him?

Comment: No no. I am just telling that it can be avoided. nothing much. Sorry if it's seen in any other way

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] value = data.trim().split(".");
if(value.length!=2){
  //throw error
}
```

for data=23. 
the value length will be 1. ;)

Answer (score 0):

use regex to match something like `^(\d+|\d+\.\d+)$`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just append a '0' to the user input if it ends with '.'
There are already too many unfriendly messages form badly written apps.

Answer (score 0):

just use `Float.parseFloat(string)` and catch `NumberFormatException`, which is thrown if string does not contain a parsable float.

Then you will be sure that your string is correct. And if exception will be thrown, you can notify user that entered value is invalid.